# Change a value depending on drag of speed on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the value of a number based on sliding my finger. I am currently using ACTION_MOVE to change the value when I drag across my view but if I drag to fast the number barely changes. If I drag slowly I can get the correct number.

Is there a way to make the change quicker depending on the speed of the motion. I am looking into Velocity Tracker but this only returns the speed of the move and I need to make the change while dragging my finger.

Is there an optimization needed to detect ACTION_MOVE in real-time?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am changing images from an array of images while sliding my finger. The change happens however I can only go through the complete array when moving my finger slow, if I move my finger fast it will only change through a small percentage of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More like pseudo code right now, but Here is what I would do:

1. Extend the image view to check if the event x value is between the starting x value of the image view and the width as such:

   private void checkFingerPosition(int eventXPosition) {

   ```
   if(eventXPosition > this.X && eventXPosition < this.x + this.getWidth())
       imageInterface.showImage(this.getDrawable());
   ```

   }
2. I would create the interface that your activity would have to implement

   public interface ImageInterface {

   ```
   public void showImage(Drawable drawable);
   ```

   }
3. In your activity, implement the ImageInterface like so

   implements ImageInterface

   @Override
   public void showImage(Drawable drawable) {
       //TODO - show drawable here 
   }
4. Then take your touch event ACTION_MOVE, report the x value to all you image  views like so:

   ACTION_MOVE:
       for(ExtendedImageView extendedImageView : ExtendedImageViewArray) {

   ```
       entendedImageView.checkFingerPosition(event.X);

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used the checkFingerPosition idea but had to due something different in the end. Even with the interface the image wasn't updating as quickly as I needed it and part was due to the lag in touch events. I ended up getting the difference from one move to the next, dividing it by a percentage of the image I calculated for what I needed, and calling the redraw function with a handler.postdelay. I will post the code later on.